# call postgres store procedure in multitenancy

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have multiple schemas (`schema1`, `schema2`) in my Postgres database.

I m using liquibase and declare create procedure in each schema. In my example Procedure do only a `select name from users;`

Psql command `\df` shows me the function in each schema. All seems to be good

Now in java when I call my procedure with jdbctemplate with schema `schema1`, execute is done but i got table users not exist. I don t know why because table users exist on each schema.
I have add schema name as parameter to my procedure and do a set search_path to schema name at the beginning of my procedure and all work fine.

But why do I need to set search_path in my procedure? My procedure is already defined on each schema and I set the schema name in the jdbctemplate call?
Why my users table is not found if I don't set `search_path`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don‘t want to set `search_path` you have to reference the table with its fully qualified name. That is `schema_name.table_name`. This is because `search_path` defaults to `"$user", public` so in your case (unless you have a schema matching your username)

```
select name from users;
```

resolves as

```
select name from public.users;
```

instead of

```
select name from schema1.users;
```

Comment: yes i understand this, but when i execute my procedure (remember my procedure was created on each schema), so it will be executed on this schema by default not on public no?

Comment: No. The `search_path` does not depend on the schema your function is located in.